# Low Replace problem inside a snippet

Tags: low-replace

Here is my code in a snippet. Basically what low_replace does is just to convert spaces to dashes.

```
{exp:low_replace find="SPACE" replace="-"}
    {permalink="product"}/
    {field_a}-
    {related_entries id="foo"}
        {foo_name}
    {/related_entries}
    -{field_b}
    {if bar != ''}-{bar}{/if}
    {related_entries id="test"}-
        {test_name}
    {/related_entries}/
{/exp:low_replace}
```

When I tried it, I got this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/test/public_html/system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(683) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse order strikes again. The conditional inside the tag is an advanced one and will be parsed *after* all the tags. That means it is still present when the replace tag is processed, creating code like this:

```
{if-bar-!=-''}-{bar}{/if}
```

Which is likely to cause the template parser to choke when it tries to parse it.